# why does my application not appear on my emulator?

Tags: android, android-activity, emulation, launcher

I have created an android application using eclipse, but when i run it, i get the following message 
[2011-01-13 18:15:55 - BookSwap] No Launcher activity found!
[2011-01-13 18:15:55 - BookSwap] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
however my manifest file has defined a launcher:

```
<application android:icon= "@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".bookswap"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".BuyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SellActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".FreecycleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        </activity>
            </activity>
                </activity>

</application>
```

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason you're nesting your activities

```
<application android:icon= "@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".bookswap"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
    <activity android:name=".BuyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
    <activity android:name=".SellActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
    <activity android:name=".FreecycleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: can you tell me how i should write it?

Comment: This is how you should write it.